# Прокрутка Ползунка input[type=range] при достижении Div'a

Tags: javascript

Есть Ползунок (input[type=range]) - как можно поменять его положение при достижении определеного Div'a 
 - знаю что можно использовать pageYOffset 
 - но для адаптации это не очень подходит - может есть решения

спасибо -

```
<div id="1"></div>

<div id="2"></div>

<div id="3"></div>

<div id="4"></div>
      <input id='damodara' type="range"  value="1" min="1" max="16" step="1" oninput="fun1();">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var footer = document.getElementById("footer");

document.onscroll = function() {
var top = footer.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var heightScreen = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var g = top - heightScreen;
if (g <=0){
 window.scrollBy(0, -footer.offsetTop);
 //вы не сможете увидеть футер
} 
}
```

```css
body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-around;
}

div{
width: 50%;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Или речь не о скролле?)

**UPD:**

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
 scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
 max = input.max,
 min = input.min,
 maxSection = max-min,
 heightSection = scrollHeight/maxSection;

document.addEventListener("scroll", changeInput)

function changeInput(){
var value = input.value,
 scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
 nowSection = Math.floor(scrollTop/heightSection);
  input.value = nowSection;
}
```

```css
body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-around;
}

div{
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px;
}
input{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: ну да - речь о том - как менять положение бегунка при скроле

Comment: Дополнил ответ .

Comment: Спасибо большое